# Bug android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I don't know how to solve that type of error, it was after i updated android studio in 3.0.1, and when i follow the link they is an error the link like "error 404". What should i do.
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.

> Could not find com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:26.0.2.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/SDK/extras/m2repository/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/SDK/extras/m2repository/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.jar
>         file:/C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.pom
>         file:/C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.jar
>         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.pom
>         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.jar
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.pom
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.jar
>         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.pom
>         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.jar
>         https://maven.google.com/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.pom
>         https://maven.google.com/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/26.0.2/dagger-compiler-26.0.2.jar
>     Required by:
>         project :app

Comment: Show your gradle files

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.climb.eip.climb"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 13):

Add google() in your buildscript in the build.gradle file of project.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    ...
    // You need to add the following repository to download the
    // new plugin.
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
}
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: Thanks man, this was exactly what I was looking, actually is in the docs but I didn't read well